# An architecture that allows for dynamic filter/querying of Repository<SomeDomainModel>

Tags: .net, linq, architecture, domain-driven-design, repository

I'm looking for a solid architecture that will solve the following problem:

As a user i want to dynamically filter some database of Persons, by dynamically adding criterias.
I also want to be able to batch-update only chosen fields to the database, based on the results of the filter.

**The following is true:**

- I have a 3-tiered solution (GUI, Business Layer, Data Access Layer).
- Suppose I have a `Repository<Person>`, the `Person` is the domain model.
- The repository supports linq and can give me: `IQueryable<T> GetAll()`

**I got some ideas:**

- I'm thinking of using Dynamic Expression API, which extends LINQ functionality so i can dynamically add search criterias.
- I've looked at NHibernate QueryBuilder, and that might be something to borrow ideas from.

**Solution Theories:**
So, anyway I'm thinking of the GUI asking the DomainModel to describe itself (what properties exists, and what operators are allowed, and what are the allowed valuetypes)
That way, I could render some cascading dropdowns for the properties and allowed operators.
I'm thinking of describing properties either from a method in the Model, for example: `DescribeMyself();`
And then combining this with decorating the properties with Attributes.

**Questions:**
So what about describing properties for a Model, how would you do that? For example, the property: `string Name`, should be searchable with either an operator of `Equals`, or an operator of Like.
What about enums ? Imagine `MyGenderEnum Gender`. When doing an Equals filter, i need to describe that it must be matched to either of any value in the given Enum.

Something to think about!

Answer (score 0):

That's a rather broad question.

Just some points:

- Dynamically adding search criteria to an `IQueryable<T>` is supported out of the box. Just add a call to `Where` for each criteria:

  `repository.GetAll<Person>().Where(x => criteria1(x)).Where(x => criteria2(x));`
- Making the model describe itself is something I wouldn't do. I would create a new class, similar to Fluent NHibernates `ClassMap<T>` or Fluent Validations `AbstractValidator<T>`.